# Detect which properties are used in code from json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's imagine I have a JSON file with some properties:

**en.json**

```
{
 "age": "18",
 "name": "Andrew",
 "lastName": "LastName"
}
```

And also we have connected files that use properties from this JSON file, imagine it is `src` folder and there are some files:

**src/index.js**

```
import messages from './en.json'

function App() {

 return <div>{messages.age}</div>
}
```

**src/other.js**

```
import messages from './en.json'

function Other(){
  return <div>{messages.name}</div>
}
```

As you can see I don't use `lastName` variable, I need to write some script that will be detecting which variables are used in code and will create a new file with only those variables, but I don't really know how to make it. Does anyone have any ideas? Should I read each file in `src` folder and then detect which property goes after `messages.` word, or is there any better way to make it ?

Comment: Usually, as far as I understand your case, you should use some library like intl or i18n. Is something stopping you from using them?

Comment: yes, I know about it, but we need some particular solution, and I need to make what I've described above @YovchoKalev

Comment: Is there any solution for what I've described?

Comment: Is there any particular requirement for creating a file with only the used variables? I can see the [**tree shaking**](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) pattern here and majority of package bundlers do support `JSON tree shaking`. Further, you can perform named imports from `json` as such `import { name } from './en.json'`.

Comment: I think now maybe I can make smth like exports.messages = ["age", "firstName"] -detect this in each file where I use variables , and by node script get data about used variables. and then by this data filter my file ?

Answer (score 0):

There is (almost) no way to detect if the properties are used in any files.

To be sure, you would have to write kind of an own javascript interpreter, or maybe a babel plugin.

If you are able to be sure that all the code using the properties you want to detect is executed when you try to detect it, you might add a proxy, like:

```
let data = {
    "age": "18",
    "name": "Andrew",
    "lastName": "LastName"
};

const used = [];
data = new Proxy(data, { get: function(target, prop){
    used.push(prop);
    return Reflect.get(target, prop);
}});

console.log('data.age:', data.age);
console.log('data.lastName:', data.lastName);
console.log('used:', used);
```

Some libraries solve the problem by requiring to define the properties inside a specific function call, like

```
import { defineProperties } from 'some-library';
 
const data = defineProperties({
    "age": "18",
    "name": "Andrew",
    "lastName": "LastName"
});
```

But even this needs to go through babel, or being executed, each file manually.